Does Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle Imply the universe is finite/periodic?
Does Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle imply the universe is either finite or periodic?
Heisenberg's uncertainty principle says your position can't be a "known" because the Fourier transform of a delta function has infinite positional uncertainty, but doesn't that mean the opposite is true as well?  That is to say, if there's a limit of the form "you can't have infinite velocity" then there are are only a finite number of harmonics implying a finite/periodic universe.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

finite variance does not imply a compact support in either domain, e.g., $e^{-x^2/2}$, see Eq. #206 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform


That is to say, if there's a limit of the form "you can't have infinite velocity" then there are are only a finite number of harmonics implying a finite/periodic universe.

Relativity says that the speed with which interactions propagate is limited, which also limits the maximal speed (and hence also the momentum) of particles. This does not contradict the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, which merely states that the uncertainties of momentum and position are related:
$$
\sigma_p\sigma_x\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$
The fact that the uncertainty of the momentum is limited (the distribution of momenta has finite tails) simply means that the position of a particle cannot be measured with an infinite precision.
Related: Are there any theoretical reasons why we cannot measure the position of a particle with zero error?

Although relativistic momentum is not bounded.

If you are confined to a finite interval of space where your wave function must be $0$ outside the interval, then there are discrete solutions to the Schrodinger equation. For the simple case of a square well, the solutions are sinusoidal where a half integer number of waves must fit in the well.
If there is no well, then any wavelength can be a solution.
You can form solutions by adding sinusoidal solutions. You can form a delta function solution by adding all wavelengths.
To do this, you need to include infinitely high wavelengths, which have infinite momentum and infinite energy. So an infinitely narrow delta function is not physical.
If you do not include wavelengths shorter than some cutoff, you can form a narrow peak, but not infinitely narrow.
